# cp: invalid option -- 'D'

Tags: linux, find, cp, mv

My goal is to find all .pdf files from multiple subfolder structures and then move them to another folder.

For this I have assembled the following.

```
find /mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/01_Firmen -iname \*.pdf -type f | xargs cp -t /mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/Paperless_input/
```

But as an error you get the following:

```
root@Tower:/mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/01_Firmen# find "/mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/01_Firmen" -iname \*.pdf -type f | xargs cp -t "/mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/Paperless_input"
cp: invalid option -- 'D'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

I try diffrent options and get some help in the Unraid Discord.

Comment: Maybe you have a filename whose name starts with `-D `?  The simple solution would be to find it, see if it is junk, and delete it ... along with similar troublesome junk.

Comment: There is nothing to find with find ./ -name "-D"

Comment: To diagnose the problem, replace `xargs` by `xargs -n 1` and `cp` by `echo cp`. As @StephenC says, this will likely show a file whose name start with `-D`.  There are plenty of other file names that can cause problems, particularly names with space characters. If you're GNU findutils, consider using `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: Try `find ./ -name "-D\*"`; i.e. **starts with** "-D".

Comment: I have renamed a file so that there is a "-D" at the beginning. However, I can't find it with any of the suggested commands.

I also tried the method of @Keith Thompson.
It worked fine, but somehow it seems extremely strange to me that the destination path is at the beginning, where the source path actually is. Everything seems to be truncated too.
Here is an example of what the echo resulted in: 

cp -t /mnt/user/Data/01_Personal_Documents/Paperless_input/ 2021.11.25,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a hint from a Friend of mine.
The correct comand looks like this:

```
find "/mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/01_Firmen" -iname \*.pdf -type f -print0  | xargs -0 cp -t "/mnt/user/Data/01_Persönliche_Dokumente/Paperless_input"
```

for the `find` command, I added `-print0` which means:

> print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null
> character (instead of the newline character that -print uses). This
> allows file names that contain newlines or other types of white space
> to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output.

for the `xargs` command I added `0` which means:

> -0 : input items are terminated by null character instead of white spaces.

basically removing any characters that would screw with the result of `find`

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, and yes, `printf0` with `xargs -0` is the correct solution, but please read the description careully, "items are terminated by null character instead of spaces". This means the `\0` char is the "line-ending" that is used or processing AND means you can have `\r\'n`, spaces, tabs, and other embedded in your ilename, but it will still be processed correctly. It's NOT removing any characters from the filename. Good luck!